# Cannot configure SSD in Disk Management

Tags: windows-8, ssd

[image]

This is a new laptop with Windows 8 preinstalled.

It has a 1TB HDD + 16 Gigabyte SSD installed on it. I'm trying to use the SSD but I cannot see the drive on my computer.

Then I went into Disk Management, to which I found out that every single options are disabled. Which means I cannot initialize, assign a drive letter or do anything useful to it.

I've confirmed that the drive is activated from UEFI.

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: At a guess, you need to elevate permissions to administrator. That image is just a little overcompressed and hard to read.

Comment: What model of laptop is it? Some new laptops come with ssds for hard disk caching.... They speed up reads and writes from the main drive.

Comment: @pjc50 It's with administrator privilege

Comment: @GerryEgan Seriously? That really might be it, does that mean I can't use the drive for regular purposes? (16 gig didn't seem much sense to me, I thought it was for putting your OS and any other performance critical softwares)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its looks very likely to be a Hybrid hard drive see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hybrid_drive) but without the model of the laptop or drive I cannot say for sure.

If you confirm it is in fact a Hybrid drive you will not be able to use if for your own storage needs, the hard disk controller will determine the most used sectors of the disk (the "hot" sectors) and move them to SSD storage to speed up disk access, you cannot decide what is cached.